# Cacheing html, javascript, css with android webview

Tags: android-webview

I have done the following in my webviewSetting but the files are still not saved in the cache:

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NORMAL);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 8);

    String appCachePath = activity.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath + "/cache");
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

any ideas?